# How do I make the bash terminal use my "home" custom Palette color scheme over an ssh connection?

Tags: bash, ssh, xterm

There are colors when I `ls` when connected to the remote system using xterm-256color, but they are not the palette colors I have selected in my profile. I had this working before, but recently had to reinstall Ubuntu on my local computer and was unable to create a backup, so I know it is a problem with the local system. The old system was 15.04, and I now have 16.04 installed. I tried changing `ls --color="auto"` to `ls --color` in .bashrc. I also tried adding `source ~/.bashrc` to my .bash_profile. I added a case statement to my local .bashrc containing `export CLICOLOR="YES"`, which also did not work.
This can be done manually by copying the output of `echo $LS_COLORS` on the local machine, and pasting it in .bashrc of the remote system as `export LS_COLORS='foo'`, but I am specifically looking for an automated way to accomplish this without modifying the .bashrc on the remote machine.

Comment: dont use xterm for this. also, the terminal you see on your machine, even if it is a remote session, is still following the rules of your local machine.  Use some other terminal emulator besides xterm.  or set xterm to match the other terminal emulators you use.

Comment: It's unclear.  Are you running `ls --color` on the remote machine, and the colors are not showing up?  Or do you want to alias `ls` to mean `ls --color`on the remote machine just as it is by default on ubuntu?